# VIM-Go Debugger on Windows results in "Goroutine not found"

Tags: go, vim, vim-plugin

I am setting up a vim-go environment on Windows, which is working for the most part. The one thing I cannot get to work is the debugger. I start it with *:GoDebugStart*. This already leads to a lot of errors regarding the *debug layer=rpc*.
Then I get more rpc related errors when trying to create the breakpoint. At the end when starting to debug with *:GoDebugNext* it complains about *Goroutine not found*. Does anybody have any similar issues or has an idea what this could be or what is missing?
Thanks!

Here is some of the error output:

```
ERR: 2019-09-24T16:43:37+02:00 info layer=debugger launching process with args: [C:\Users\henri\AppData\Local\Temp\VIA7813.tmp]

ERR: 2019-09-24T16:43:53+02:00 debug layer=rpc <- RPCServer.CreateBreakpoint(rpc2.CreateBreakpointIn{"Breakpoint":{"id":0,"name":"","addr":0,"file":"C:/Users/henri/go/src/local/flightGenerator/readAirports.go","line":38,"Cond":"","continue":false,"traceReturn":false,"goroutine":false,"stacktrace":0,"LoadArgs":null,"LoadLocals":null,"hitCount":null,"totalHitCount":0}})

ERR: 2019-09-24T16:43:53+02:00 info layer=debugger created breakpoint: &api.Breakpoint{ID:1, Name:"", Addr:0x4d179f, File:"C:/Users/henri/go/src/local/flightGenerator/readAirports.go", Line:38, FunctionName:"main.main", Cond:"", Tracepoint:false, TraceReturn:false, Goroutine:false, Stacktrace:0, Variables:[]string(nil), LoadArgs:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), LoadLocals:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), HitCount:map[string]uint64{}, TotalHitCount:0x0}

ERR: 2019-09-24T16:43:53+02:00 debug layer=rpc -> *rpc2.CreateBreakpointOut{"Breakpoint":{"id":1,"name":"","addr":5052319,"file":"C:/Users/hen
```

Also, after starting the debugging process with *:GoDebugNext* I get error stating that:

current goroutine not found...
vim-go: dictionary required

Comment: What are "lot of errors"? Being errors, they probably tell you something important.

Comment: I added some of the error messages, though they are longer per line - since the debugger crashes I cannot scroll further to the right.

Comment: What guide you used to install vim-go on windows?

Comment: I used the official guide at _https://github.com/fatih/vim-go_. All I did was to clone the repo into plugins/start/vim-go and called _:GoInstallBinaries_

Comment: where is your plugins/start folder on windows?

Comment: ~/vimfiles/pack/plugins/start

Comment: Though nerdtree and vimairline are in vimfiles\pack\dist\start

Comment: I am seeing the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug and I filed it as bug #2511 with the developer on github. Just in case somebody else has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading here [Request: option to suppress delve debugging logs](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/issues/2200)

> They are not errors, they're just the diagnostics that delve sends on
>   stderr , hence ERR. You're free to ignore them.

Comment: Thanks, but the whole vim crashes the moment the errors appear. No debugging is possible.

Comment: Please look at this screenshot for more details: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/55752765/65526532-874d8580-def1-11e9-933a-394aa798d619.jpg